# Why can't MMA find the series of this function at 0?

Tags: series-expansion

I want to expand the following two functions into series at `x = 0`, but MMA(Version 12.1.1) runs all the time and cannot return results:

```
Series[Integrate[Log[1 + Sqrt[t^3]], {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 5}]
Series[Integrate[Sqrt[Sin[t]^3], {t, 0, 1 - Cos[x]}], {x, 0, 5}, 
 Assumptions -> (x > 0)]
```

What can I do to find their series expansion quickly?

Comment: You could perhaps interchange the order of the integration and the series expansion. You would need to think about the constant term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new in M11.3 function [`AsymptoticIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate) for this purpose:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Log[1+Sqrt[t^3]], {t, 0, x}, {x, 0, 5}]
AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[Sin[t]^3], {t, 0, x}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> -(x^4/8) + (2 x Sqrt[x^3])/5 + 2/33 x^4 Sqrt[x^3]

> (2 x Sqrt[x^3])/5 - 1/18 (x^3)^(3/2)

Answer (score 3):

Include `Assumptions->x>0` inside `Integrate`

```
Series[Integrate[Log[1 + Sqrt[t^3]], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0], {x, 0, 5}]
(*(2 x^(5/2))/5 - x^4/8*)


Series[Integrate[Sqrt[Sin[t]^3], {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> (x > 0)], {x, 0, 5}] 
(*(2 x^(5/2))/5 - x^(9/2)/18*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I run your modified code in mma12.1. It takes about 280 seconds to output the results. Do you have any way to improve the calculation speed?

Comment: No idea. In mma v12 it takes 3 seconds to evaluate.

Comment: Since both `Series` and `Integrate` take assumptions, it generally would be better to use `Assuming[x > 0, Series[ Integrate[ f[t], {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 5}]]`, even more so when `Simplify` is used: `Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[ Series[ Integrate[ f[t], {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 5}]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you very much. The speed has been greatly improved after using your method.